# Expo fails to build, MaxListenersExceeded

Tags: react-native, expo

So i tried running expo build:android and in console i get Request failed with status code 413, when i go to Metro bundler in browser i have error

MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 change listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit

I tried solvng by using emitter.setMaxListeners() but i got

You attempted attempted to import the Node standard library module "events" from "components\FirstView.js". It failed because React Native does not include the Node standard library. Read more at https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/introduction/faq.html#can-i-use-nodejs-packages-with-expo

Does anyone know how to solve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem was in my asset folder where i had files that were over 50MB. When i deleted them Expo built my app successfully